# Xamarin Forms app fail to install in iPhone. Not installed because its integrity could not be verified. The provisioning profile is banned

Tags: iphone, xamarin

I have an app developed in Xamarin Forms + Visual Studio for Mac that I can't no longer install in any iPhone.

I'm enrolled in Apple Enterprise developer, and recently my account has expired, the account holder didn't renew the account on-time, and the account was closed by apple.
After many support contacts with apple, they managed to open the account again and let us renew it.
After my account holder give me access again to that account has admin, I had to recreate all certificates and provisioning profiles, because all have been revoked.

The thing that's happening is that after installing the app, the app stays with a small cloud icon next to the app's icon. When tapping on the app's icon, I get an error message: "This app was not installed because its integrity could not be verified."

This happens to me all the time. I tried to clean and delete all certificates and provisioning profiles, recreate them again, and the same error occurs all the time.
I even created a new app (HelloWorld), new bundle identifier, new certificate and provisioning profile, but the same error occurs.
I noticed that if I connect the iPhone to my macBook with a usb cable, and have the console streaming the iPhone installation process, I see that the error has to do with signing. "Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/*****.iOS.app : 0xe8008024 (The provisioning profile is banned.) - This app was not installed because its integrity could not be verified."

So, the process of distributing an enterprise app isn't new to me, I have this app running since 2017.

I have to create an iOS Distribution certificate, download it and install in on keychain.
I have to create an InHouse Distribution provisioning profile, associate it with the identifier (the app bundle ID) and with the distribution certificate, download it and install it on XCode.
I then have to build my project in Release/iPhone, choosing the distribution provisioning profile in the Bundle Signing option of the iOS project.
Then I have to archive the project and distribute it in Enterprise mode, choosing the distribution provisioning profile. After that I have an IPA file signed and ready to distribute.

Since I'm in Enterprise program, it has to be distributed in-House. I choose to do OTA, in a web page hosted on my company (With IIS under a Windows server). I have to create a manifest.plist file and it has to be configured to allow the download of the IPA.
I usually use XCode distribution because it generates this file for me. It has to have the correct bundle identifier, and the url to the IPA file (with https protocol).
Oh, I still have to configure the IIS to have the mime types for .ipa and .plist extensions.
So, this isn't new to me, and should be suffice to allow an iPhone that navigates to the webpage, and clicks on the link (the link has to call the plist file with "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=[PATH_TO_PLIST_FILE]" with https protocol)
to trigger the download and installation of the app.
After installing the app, when tapping on it the user still has to trust the enterprise that developed the app, by verifying the certificate (Settings - General - VPN & Device Management).
When I navigate to "Settings - General - VPN & Device Management", I see that no certificate has been installed as well.

I know I'm signing the app the correct way. I tried many different processes to sign and distribute the app (manually choosing the provisioning profile, letting XCode automatically create a provisioning profile), but the error is always the same.

I tried many times to talk to apple about this, because it's as if my company is somehow blacklisted or banned, since the account once expired and closed by apple. I know they opened it again, but could it still has somewhere in their confused data model some flag that still marks my company has "not trusted" ?

Please, does anyone ever experienced this situation, or might know what's happening ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I simply can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I can't figure out why the app fails to install on any iPhone with the error :"This app was not installed because its integrity could not be verified.", related to signing issues: "The provisioning profile is banned.". Just wanted to know if anybody has a clue why do I get this error.

Comment: Firstly, you can try to create a new empty project in Xcode and then use the profile and certificate you created on it to see if it can be successfully deployed to the iPhone, which is a way to check if there's a problem with your account. Secondly, you can check if the certificate you used to create the profile is the development certificate that exists in the Mac's keychain.

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT, thanks, I already created in XCode an HelloWorld project, just to take VS out of the picture, but the same error occurs. And in XCode I tried both manual and automatic signing. I'm not using the development certificate, I'm using the distribution certificate.

Comment: If your empty project on Xcode still can't be deployed to iPhone via manual or automatic signing, you can contact Apple to check if there is any problem with your account.